# Aligning textviews on the left and right edges in Android layout

Tags: android

I am getting started with Android. I am having trouble getting a simple layout going.

I would like to use a `LinearLayout` to position two `TextViews` in a single row. One `TextView` on the left hand side, the other on the right hand side (analogous to float:left, float:right in CSS).

Is that possible, or do I need to use a different `ViewGroup` or further layout nesting to accomplish it?

Here's what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="10sp">
<TextView android:id="@+id/mytextview1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="somestringontheleftSomestring" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/mytextview2" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:ellipsize="end"
    android:text="somestringontheright" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 302, accepted):

Use a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) with [`layout_alignParentLeft`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentLeft) and [`layout_alignParentRight`](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_alignParentRight):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
        android:id="@+id/mytextview1"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:id="@+id/mytextview2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, [you should probably be using `dip` (or `dp`) rather than `sp` in your layout](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence).  `sp` reflect text settings as well as screen density so they're usually only for sizing text items.

Comment: To prevent the contents from overlapping, might also want to add 'android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mytextview2"' to the first textview

Comment: For dynamic tables, you can do :
TableRow.LayoutParams col1Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
  // Wrap-up the content of the row
  col1Params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  col1Params.width = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
  
  // Set the gravity to center the gravity of the column
  col1Params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

Comment: For better compatibility and support for different device screens, use "android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"" (when using layout_alignParentRight) and "android:layout_alignParentStart="true"" (when using layout_alignParentLeft).

Answer (score 90):

You can use the gravity property to "float" views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Left Aligned"
            />

        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Right Aligned"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems this doesn't cause both items to be on the same line

Comment: Doesn't gravity only affect the "text alignment"?

Comment: sorry, its working. I had forgot to add android:layout_weight="1". After adding that its fine.

Answer (score 18):

It can be done with `LinearLayout` (less overhead and more control than the Relative Layout option). Give the second view the remaining space so `gravity` can work. Tested back to API 16.

[image: Proof]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aligned left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Aligned right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want to limit the size of the first text view, do this:

Adjust weights as required. Relative layout won't allow you to set a percentage weight like this, only a fixed dp of one of the views

[image: Proof 2]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aligned left but too long and would squash the other view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="Aligned right" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 9):

Even with Rollin_s's tip, Dave Webb's answer didn't work for me.  The text in the right `TextView` was still overlapping the text in the left `TextView`.

I eventually got the behavior I wanted with something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mytextview1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/mytextview2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mytextview1"
    android:gravity="right"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that mytextview2 has `"android:layout_width"` set as `"match_parent"`.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 4):

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Hello world" />

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Gud bye" />
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This Code will Divide the control into two equal sides.

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
    <TextView
        android:text = "Left Side"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:id = "@+id/txtLeft"/>

    <TextView android:text = "Right Side"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight = "1"
        android:id = "@+id/txtRight"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Very simple and helpful answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want the left and right elements to wrap content but have the middle space

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Space
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways to accomplish this, I would do something like this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="YOUR TEXT ON THE RIGHT"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="YOUR TEXT ON THE LEFT"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dave Webb's answer did work for me. Thanks!
Here my code, hope this helps someone!

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="ABA Type"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <TextView
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:minWidth="30px"
        android:minHeight="30px"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:id="@+id/txtABAType"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Image:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IpkX.png)