# Align UITextView Right and Left.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have UITextView, which is left aligned.

When last word does not fit on current line it goes to next line leaving spaces on end of line.

which does not give good look and feel.

So, what I want that  if words of particular line feels the spaces left at end.

**i.e.** Spaces between two words can dynamically varies.

Here I am giving example of Scenario:

The width of text view,never put off until (here tomorrow does not fit,so it goes to next line leaving spaces).

Tomorrow what you can avoid all together.

So, problem is it does look good.

What I want is:

The width of text view never put off, until (varying spaces shown by)
tomorrow -what -you -can
avoid --all -- together.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you are asking about is Justified Alignment.  See this earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301519/justified-alignment-in-uitextview-iphone

Comment: Check if u are looking for this


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099249/aligning-textviews-on-the-left-and-right-edges-in-android-layout

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no setting for justified aligment for text you only have center, left and right. If you want justified aligment where every line has the same amount of characters or something like that you can format the text entered to have carriage returns after x amount of characters or words, or something like that.

Comment: This is no substitute for justified alignment, obviously, because the alignment mechanics relies on word and glyph spacing.

Comment: @Costique  so can u tell me a solution

Comment: @Raj See the link in **jonkroll**'s comment for the `CATextLayer` answer.

Comment: hi, to achieve this property I want to put hyphen at the end. how can i do that e.g.  this is examp-  ple code