# Keeping ProgressBar from overlapping the right-most view in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-relativelayout, overlap

How can I properly keep the ProgressBar from overlapping the right-most view? Note that I do not want to use a TableLayout.  I have also already read this excellent SOF [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099249/aligning-textviews-on-the-left-and-right-edges-in-android-layout).

[image: ProgressBar_overlap]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel_left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="LLL" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RIGHT"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="RRR" />
</RelativeLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rel_left"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="80" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >
    <!-- Align parent left cause this textview to be on the left! -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="LLL" />

    <!-- Align parent right cause this textview to be on the right! -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="RRR" />

    <!-- Now we want this progressbar to take up all the space in between. Just specify the 'layout_toLeftOf' and 'layout_toRightOf' properites! -->
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pb"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5sp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="80" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Im not sure why you have the textviews wrapped in their own RelativeLayout, I think this may just be a misunderstanding on your part, as you can force the textviews themselves to be on the left and right

Comment: This works! To answer your question, I have them wrapped in their own RelativeLayout because I am going to add another TextView to "rel_left" and "RIGHT".

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution if you have 5 items in a RelativeLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:padding="10dp" >

<!-- Align parent left cause this TextView to be on the left! -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="LLL" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
    android:text="100" />

<!-- Align parent right cause this TextView to be on the right! -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="RRR" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
    android:text="2" />

<!-- Now we want this ProgressBar to take up all the space in between. Just specify the 'layout_toLeftOf' and 'layout_toRightOf' properites! -->

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5sp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right_number"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left_number"
    android:max="100"
    android:paddingLeft="5sp"
    android:paddingRight="5sp"
    android:progress="80" />

</RelativeLayout>
```