# Textview display in android

Tags: android, textview

In my application i am displaying textvalue one below the other from database which is integer.What i want is i have to make this integer value to be right aligned.Is it possible to right align the text.

My layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:paddingTop="4dip"
     android:paddingBottom="6dip"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"

     >    
<TableLayout 
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:paddingRight="2dip"
       >

    <TableRow  >
 <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Income">
     </TextView>      
        <TextView             
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Expense" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp">
     </TextView>                     

    </TableRow>    
        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse"   android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView  android:id="@+id/text40" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/houseinctot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp" >
     </TextView>   

          <TextView  android:id="@+id/text41" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp"  >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/houseexptot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Household:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp" android:gravity="right"
             >
     </TextView>    

    </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


 <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView  android:id="@+id/text42" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_span="3">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
     </TextView>     

           <TextView  android:id="@+id/text43" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/trlexptot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Travel:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"  android:gravity="right"
            >
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>


     <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>


     <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView  android:id="@+id/text44" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:" android:layout_span="4">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
     </TextView>  

           <TextView  android:id="@+id/text45" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/eduexptot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Education:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"  android:gravity="right"
            >
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>

         <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView  android:id="@+id/text46" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Group4:" android:layout_span="4">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="group4" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp">
     </TextView>  

           <TextView  android:id="@+id/text47" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Group4:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/grp4exptot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="group4:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"  android:gravity="right"
            >
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow> 

            <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <View
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FF909090"
                android:padding="2dip" />
        </TableRow>

             <TableRow  android:layout_marginTop="30px">
 <TextView  android:id="@+id/text48" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Group5:" android:layout_span="4">
     </TextView>     
      <TextView
           android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="group5" android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp">
     </TextView>  

           <TextView  android:id="@+id/text49" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Group5:" android:layout_marginLeft="-150dp" >
     </TextView>            
        <TextView             
            android:id="@+id/grp5exptot" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="group5:" android:layout_marginLeft="-70dp"  android:gravity="right"
            >
     </TextView>    
 </TableRow>
```

My format of display should like this (I am dispalying 2 column like structure in the layout with space between them):

```
12233      67999 
    9          8  
   48         56 
 4567        576
```

But it is showing like this:

```
 12233     45345
 9         6  
 48        677
 4567.     3566
```

If i use gravity:right means:
It is going to right extreme of the screen and overlapping value there.

Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Following Link helps you. [Align Text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099249/aligning-textviews-on-the-left-and-right-edges-in-android-layout

Comment: can you please upload an image that shows how the final view should look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated your layout XML to solve the text overlapping issues. find the updated layout XML file here

- Instead of giving margins to align table columns, use `0dp` as value for `layout_width` parameter and value `1` for `layout_weight` parameter for your textviews.

```
<TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Income" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Expense" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tablerowhouse"
    android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text40"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Household:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/houseinctot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="Household:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text41"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Household:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/houseexptot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Household:" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text42"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Travel:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trlinctot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="Travel" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text43"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Travel:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/trlexptot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Travel:" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF909090"
        android:padding="2dip" 
        />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text44"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Education:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eduinctot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="Education" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text45"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Education:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/eduexptot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="Education:" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF909090"
        android:padding="2dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text46"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Group4:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grp4inctot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="group4" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text47"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:text="Group4:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grp4exptot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="group4:" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF909090"
        android:padding="2dip" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:layout_marginTop="30px" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text48"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Group5:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grp5inctot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:text="group5" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text49"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:text="Group5:" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grp5exptot"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="group5:" >
    </TextView>
</TableRow>
```

**Note:** If you provide a drawing that shows the expected screen layout, experts here may be able to help you.

Comment: Hi sunil..Thanks sunil i got 50% of my problem solved.Now The column2 datas are align right but column1 datas are not aligned.

Comment: @prakash.k upload the images/screenshots that shows the issue. then i can understand the current problem and check whether i can help you

Comment: @prakash.k upload image somewhere in free image hosting sites and post the links

Comment: @prakash.k use http://imgur.com till you are allowed to upload images in stackoverflow. ie, upload image in http://imgur.com and then share that link here

Comment: @prakash.k just apply the `android:gravity="right"`, in column-1 `TextViews` also

Comment: Sunil...http://www.freeimagehosting.net/ri8jb..see this link..column1 data is very right extreme to column2..i want some space between column1 value and column2..what cani do??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13838/discussion-between-prakash-k-and-sunil)

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:gravity="right">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in xml in each textview

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code for that, it may help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Layout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="12345" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="1234" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="12" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
        android:text="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```