# Android Align text to right or left

Tags: java, android

How can I move a text box to the right or left in Android?
I want to make something like this: [image: example]
I currently just used space to move it to the right but obviously this only works in a resolution that I was working on.

Comment: Use android:gravity in TextView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
android:gravity="right"
```

You can also use left, end, start, centre, etcetera.

You can view the docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html)

In this case you may also want to use:

```
android:width="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle this on the xml side of things

Probably want to use a RelativeLayout with layout_alignParentLeft and layout_alignParentRight:

see : [Aligning textviews on the left and right edges in Android layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099249/aligning-textviews-on-the-left-and-right-edges-in-android-layout)  which should be a pretty good example for you